# What is the Fourier transform of $x(t)=0.2+0.5\cdot \operatorname{sinc}^2(3t)?$

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I want to calculate the Fourier transform for the signal $x(t)=0.2+0.5\cdot \operatorname{sinc}^2(3t)$. I know that the Fourier transform for $\operatorname{sinc}^2(3t)$ is $\frac13 \operatorname{tri}\left(\frac f3\right)$ but what about the $0.2 + 0.5$ part?

Comment: The Fourier transform is linear and the Fourier transform of a constant is the Dirac delta function. Also please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry for not using MathJax. So the Fourier transform would be $δ(f) + δ(f) \cdot\ 1/3\cdot\ tri(\frac f3)$? Am I right?